# Deleting last line of every text file in drive using Batch or VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I need to create either a batch file or vbscript to delete every last line of a text file in a drive. So, a text file

```
    Hello.
    Blah blah blah.
    Goodbye.
```

will become

```
    Hello.
    Blah blah blah.
```

TIA.

*PS: I'm creating projects to learn batch and vbscript. My ultimate goal is to learn the scripting language. So, I would like to request for explanation alongside the code so that I can understand. Thanks.*

Comment: This is a commonly asked question - google it given you will quickly find a detailed walk-through. Hint google `vbscript delete last line`....

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/11/how-can-i-delete-just-the-last-line-of-a-text-file.aspx shows the code to delete the last line of a specific txt file only. Is there an equivalent of for loop in vbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a commented solution for you.

Be warned that doing something like this is potentially a dangerous operation to run across an entire drive - VBScript does not handle Unicode files very well, so if you run this against a whole drive, be sure you know what you are changing.

I have set it only to work against a sub-directoy (C:\Somedirectory) in my example you would need to change that to where ever you want to go. Also, whilst I have tested this, I can't guarantee it's not going to misbehave: Consider this - if you ran this multiple times, you would end up with a whole bunch of 0 byte (empty) files eventually!

**WARNING: This will permanently delete data that you cannot get back. I would not recommend using this blindly against an entire drive!!**

**DISCLAIMER: Use at your own risk.**

```
Option Explicit 
' Option Explicit forces all variables to be declared good way to sanity check some times.

Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForReading = 1
' Set our Contsants for manipulating files read/writes 

' Dimension our variables (in our case, the main loop only has one.. objFSO
Dim objFSO 

' Load up the FileSystemObject for our file operations later
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Call our routine to recursively scan folders for txt files.
Call Recurse("C:\SomeFolder\")

Sub Recurse(strFolderPath)
    ' This routine recursively searches a folder/drive for txt files 
    Dim objFolder, objFile, objSubFolder        

    ' Load up the Folder path into objFolder
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)

    On Error Resume Next          
    ' Instruct VBScript to continue if an error occurs.
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If Err Then
           ' If there's an error accessing the file, likely to be access denied for files in use, etc. Let's ignore and continue
           Err.clear
        Else
           If (InStr(objFile.Name, ".") > 0) Then
              'If the file's extension is "txt", chomp it! (This calls the Function FileChomp with the path\filename.txt)
              If LCase(objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "txt" Then FileChomp (objFile.Path )
           End If
        End If
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call Recurse(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Sub


Function FileChomp (FCName)
    ' This function chomps the last line of a text file.
    Dim strdata, objFile, arrlines, strlines, filesize

    ' This section gets our text file size.
    filesize = 0
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(FCName)
    FileSize = objFile.Size
    Set objFile = Nothing

    'This resets our array for lines, incase there's something in there already from last time?
    ReDim arrlines(0)

    ' Open the file for reading
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FCName, ForReading)

    ' If the filesize we retrieved earlier is greater than 0, go do this
    If FileSize > 0 then
        strLines = 0
        Do While objFile.atendofstream = false
            ' This loop reads in the file we're going to chomp and stores it line by line into arrLines as an array 
            ReDim Preserve arrLines(strLines)
            arrLines(strlines) = objFile.Readline
            strLines = strLines + 1
        Loop

        ' This sets the file as we are going to write back to it (less the last line) - BE WARNED This may not work for unicode text files.
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FCName, ForWriting)

        For strLines = 0 to UBound(arrLines) - 1
        ' This For Loop writes out the file (less the last line)
           objFile.WriteLine arrLines(strLines)
        Next
    End If

    objFile.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

## What have you tried?

Start by looking at these commands.

#### Commands

`for`,
`for /f`,
`for /r`

Use the `/?` argument for help.

#### Batch References

- [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/),
- [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/),
- [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php),
- [Computer Hope](http://www.computerhope.com/)
- [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390.aspx)

Bookmark These!

Comment: Since you hinted to use the for command, Code should be: for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir *.txt /b /s /a-d ') do [command to remove last line]

However, there seems to be no one-liner to delete the last line of file...

Answer (score 0):

This script for removing last N line, works for you:

- count the total line
- set Line = Line - N , remain just processing lines number

  ```
  @echo OFF
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

  set LINES=0
  for /f "delims==" %%I in (input.txt) do (
  set /a LINES=LINES+1    
  )

  echo Total Lines : %LINES%
  echo.

  :: n = 1 , last 1 line will be ignored 
  set /a LINES=LINES-1

  call:PrintFirstNLine > output.txt

  goto EOF

  :PrintFirstNLine
  set cur=0
  for /f "delims==" %%I in (input.txt) do (      
  echo %%I        
  ::echo !cur! : %%I      
  set /a cur=cur+1    
  if "!cur!"=="%LINES%" goto EOF
  ) 

  :EOF 

  exit /b
  ```

Here `call:PrintFirstNLine > output.txt` will give the output in an external file name as output.txt .